# Junit testing a boolean method

Tags: java, junit

i have this method i have to write a test for. I have tried different ways of trying to test but all keep failing.

this is the method i was given and can't change it at all.

```
/**
 * Tests if another BoardPiece has the same value as this BoardPiece.
 * @param other the BoardPiece to test against this BoardPiece.
 * @return true if the BoardPieces have the same value, false otherwise.
 */
public boolean equals(BoardPiece other)
{
    return this.value.equals(other.value);
}
```

and this is one of my attempts of testing it.

```
@Test
public void testEquals() {
   BoardPiece boardPiecetest = new BoardPiece("value");
   boolean q = this.value.equals(boardPiecetest);
  assertTrue(q);
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with this snippet?

Comment: Post stacktrace with problem.

Comment: What classes are the two snippets defined in? Also, your `equals()` should take an argument of `Object`. And you should implement `hashCode()` as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
@Test
public void testPositiveEquals() {
   BoardPiece boardPieceOne = new BoardPiece("value");
   assertTrue(boardPieceOne.equals(boardPieceOne));
}

@Test
public void testNegativeEquals() {
   BoardPiece boardPieceOne = new BoardPiece("value");
   BoardPiece boardPieceTwo = new BoardPiece("no value");
   assertFalse(boardPieceOne.equals(boardPieceTwo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the type of 'this.value' is String. So essentially, you a comparing a straing with a BoardPrice on the third line of the test.